# How to convert SQL inner join to lambda linq query

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-to-sql

I am new in LINQ queries
and I need help to convert my sample SQL query to LINQ lambda query

```
select * from GRecommendations 
inner join GSections
on GRecommendations.GSectionId = GSections.Id
where GSections.GaId = 646
```

Comment: We're not here to convert code for you. If you tried and you got stuck somewhere you're more than welcome to tell where *specifically* you need help. One obvious advice: don't `join` in LINQ, use navigation properties.

Comment: YES SIR YOU 'R RIGHT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different methods you can use when GRecommendations is a collection.

```
var arrResult = //UNTESTED
   GRecommendations
   .Join(GSections.Where(sec => sec.GaId.Equals(646)),
   rec => rec.GeSectionId,
   sec => sec.Id,
   (REC, SEC) => new { /*put here what you want selected*/ }
   );  //
```

or

```
var arrResult = 
(
   from rec in GRecommendations
   join rec in GSections.Where(s => s.GaId.Equals(646)) on rec.GSectionId equals sec.GaId
   select new {/*rec.something*/, /*sec.something*/}
);
```